# Bitbucket Server : Merge check - Minimum successful builds not enabling merge even after the condition is satisfied

Tags: jenkins, merge, webhooks, pull-request, bitbucket-server

I have configured Bitbucket Server to work with Jenkins by enabling a Webhook in Bitbucket with the Jenkins URL and the event being - Pull request approved. So I want a build on Jenkins to be triggered when a pull request is approved by the named reviewer.

The Jenkins job is configured to be triggered remotely using a token and that token is specified in the Bitbucket Webhook along with the Jenkins URL. This is working as expected. The Jenkins job is triggered automatically as soon as the pull request is approved by the reviewer.

But, I have also configured a merge check for the project . The merge check is enabled for minimum successful builds and the number of builds to be successful is configured to be 1. So, I expect the merge button to be enabled as the reviewer has approved the pull request and the Jenkins build has run (also success). But unfortunately, the merge button is not enabled even after all this. I also triggered a build manually on the same commit ( was success too ) but with no success on the merge button being enabled. Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here are the steps of how I fixed it.

1. Use **Bitbucket** and not **Git** as the source code management. But, Bitbucket seems to be only avaiable when creating a [Multibranch Pipeline](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-multibranch).
2. Now, that you use *Bitbucket*, install plugin [Bitbucket Branch Source](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cloudbees-bitbucket-branch-source) Plugin
3. Bitbucket appears to get the result of the build from [Bitbucket Branch Source](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cloudbees-bitbucket-branch-source) plugin

The plugin requires some configuration, this [webpage](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000053051-How-to-Trigger-Multibranch-Jobs-from-Bitbucket-Server-) helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, if in your case you have at least one failed build before the succesfull one, then you will not be able to merge until you push a new code to the PR branch.
 This answer comes after discussing it with Bitbucket's support team.